# SQL query [How to]

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, sorting, filtering

I want to achieve the following result. Thanks in advance!

I did the below to get the values from the DB

```
$allmeetings = Db::select('select t_meetings.item_id, t_meetings.title, t_contacts.name, t_meetings.date_start
        from t_meetings, t_participants, t_contacts
        where t_meetings.item_id = t_participants.meeting_first_id 
        and t_participants.app_reference2_first_id = t_contacts.item_id
        order by t_meetings.item_id');
```

That give me the following array

```
$arr = array([
    0 => [
      'item_id' => 11,
      'title' => 'Work Life Balance',
      'name' => 'Selena',
      'date_start'  => 2012-11-20 12:30:00
    ],
    1 => [
      'item_id' => 11,
      'title' => 'Work Life Balance',
      'name' => 'John',
      'date_start'  => 2012-11-20 12:30:00
    ],
    2 => [
      'item_id' => 12,
      'title' => 'Mental Wellness',
      'name' => 'David',
      'date_start'  => 2011-10-19 12:30:00
    ],
    3 => [
      'item_id' => 12,
      'title' => 'Mental Wellness',
      'name' => 'Tom',
      'date_start'  => 2011-10-19 12:30:00
    ],
  ]);
```

But instead I want to query to get something like this

```
$arr = array([
  0 => [
    'item_id' => 11,
    'title' => 'Work Life Balance',
    'name'  => 'Selena,John',
    'date_start'  => 2012-11-20 12:30:00
  ],
  1 => [
    'item_id' => 12
    'title' => 'Work Life Balance',
    'name'  => 'David, Tom',
    'date_start'  => 2012-10-19 12:30:00
  ],
]);
```

---

Comment: `select distinct ....`

Comment: Asking about SQL query post SQL code, not PHP code... Do not use comma-style JOINs.

Comment: @juergend distinct didn't work

Comment: @Akina "Do not use comma-style JOINs" Can you please explain it a bit. .

Comment: "comma style joins" are implicit joins. Use the explicit join syntax. The other one is outdated for 30 years now. Use `JOIN ON`

Comment: @juergend I am a complete newbie. Can you please give me an example of using JOIN ON in my problem?

Comment: `select m.item_id, m.title, c.name, m.date_start from t_meetings m inner join t_participants p on m.item_id = p.meeting_first_id inner join t_contacts c on p.app_reference2_first_id = c.item_id order by m.item_id`

Comment: @juergend I am getting the same array output with the code you gave. By any chance, can we do aything with the array or try any other SQL method?

Comment: yes, it is the same output. But you should use the proper join syntax for all queries in the future

Comment: BTW distinct should work. Are you really showing the correct query?

Comment: Yes, Thats the correct query. Also, tried distinct, it didnt work. Kindly look at this image https://i.ibb.co/Zfw4jyz/image.png . It will be great of you could help me with this query solution